# XML Sub element Parsing

Tags: c#, .net, xml

I am trying to read a value from the namespace but it's not working. I am using the following code which gets the descendents into a list.

```
       XDocument doc = XDocument.Parse(QueryParmeterString);
       XNamespace ns = XNamespace.Get("http://Microsoft.EnterpriseManagement.Core.Criteria/");
       var expressions = (from ds in doc.Descendants(ns + "Expression")
                       select ds).ToList();


           foreach (var foo in expressions)
                   {
                       string baa = foo.Attributes["ValueExpressionLeft"].Value;
                   }


    }
```

It's at this point I am having trouble accessing each of the objects. I need to gain access to the value left and right value of each of the properties. I have a strongly typed object ready to store the values.

```
        <Expression xmlns="http://Microsoft.EnterpriseManagement.Core.Criteria/">
          <And>
            <Expression>
              <SimpleExpression>
                <ValueExpressionLeft>
                  <Property>$Context/Property[Type='CoreIncident!System.WorkItem.Incident']/TierQueue$</Property>
                </ValueExpressionLeft>
                <Operator>Equal</Operator>
                <ValueExpressionRight>
                  <Value>$MPElement[Name="IncidentTierQueuesEnum.Tier2"]$</Value>
                </ValueExpressionRight>
              </SimpleExpression>
            </Expression>
            <Expression>
              <SimpleExpression>
                <ValueExpressionLeft>
                  <Property>$Context/Property[Type='CoreIncident!System.WorkItem.Incident']/Status$</Property>
                </ValueExpressionLeft>
                <Operator>NotEqual</Operator>
                <ValueExpressionRight>
                  <Value>$MPElement[Name="CoreIncident!IncidentStatusEnum.Resolved"]$</Value>
                </ValueExpressionRight>
              </SimpleExpression>
            </Expression>
            <Expression>
              <SimpleExpression>
                <ValueExpressionLeft>
                  <Property>$Context/Property[Type='CoreIncident!System.WorkItem.Incident']/Status$</Property>
                </ValueExpressionLeft>
                <Operator>NotEqual</Operator>
                <ValueExpressionRight>
                  <Value>$MPElement[Name="CoreIncident!IncidentStatusEnum.Closed"]$</Value>
                </ValueExpressionRight>
              </SimpleExpression>
            </Expression>
            <Expression>
              <UnaryExpression>
                <ValueExpression>
                  <GenericProperty Path="$Context/Path[Relationship='WorkItem!System.WorkItemAssignedToUser' SeedRole='Source']$">Id</GenericProperty>
                </ValueExpression>
                <Operator>IsNull</Operator>
              </UnaryExpression>
            </Expression>
          </And>
        </Expression>
```

Comment: What do you need exactly ? Is to get the value of the expression left and right of each expression?

Comment: @Lamourou Hi yes that is the case I am using linq to get the main expression entrys which returns that xml.

Comment: @Lamourou any ideas I also need the ability to get the expression type some how see way their is tags simple expression and uniury expression?

Comment: What's happen david is that answer help you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this one it may help you :

```
XDocument doc = XDocument.Parse(QueryParmeterString);
XNamespace ns = XNamespace.Get("http://Microsoft.EnterpriseManagement.Core.Criteria/");
var expressions = (from ds in doc.Root.Descendants(ns + "Expression")
                           select ds).ToList();

        foreach (var foo in expressions)
        {
            XElement expressionTypeElement = foo.FirstNode  as XElement;
            if (expressionTypeElement != null)
            {
                if (expressionTypeElement.Name.LocalName == "SimpleExpression")
                {
                    XElement valueExpressionLeft = expressionTypeElement.Element(ns +"ValueExpressionLeft");
                    XElement valueExpressionRight = expressionTypeElement.Element(ns +"ValueExpressionRight");
                    string operator = expressionTypeElement.Element(ns + "Operator").Value;
                    // do your job here 
                    //....
                }
                else if (expressionTypeElement.Name.LocalName == "UnaryExpression")
                {
                    XElement valueExpression = expressionTypeElement.Element(ns +"ValueExpression");
                    // do your job here
                    //....
                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: Perfection working brill now just have to parse the flipping elements lol and xml was ment to be easy

Comment: Perfect‚ enjoy your time by parsing elements and xml.

Comment: any idea how I Would parse this line budy